# How do I get Textadept to open PDF's with Okular?

Tags: context, okular

I'm using Elementary OS and I have the latest TexLive, Textadept, and Okular installed in the default locations, Textadept is using the configuration files from the ConTeXt distribution.  Compiling and pdf creation works fine, but Okular doesn't startup after PDF creation, I'm getting the message below. Any ideas why is it trying to use a Windows executable and how to get it to open the PDF properly and automatically?
Thanks everyone.

```
mtx-context     | pdfview methods: auto default okular pdfxcview sumatra, 
current method: sumatra (directives_pdfview_method) pdfview   | command: wine 
"sumatrapdf.exe" -reuse-instance -bg-color 0xCCCCCC "Adept_test_file.pdf" 
1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null & mtx-context     | pdfview overhead: 0.004 seconds 
system          | total runtime: 1.087 seconds
```

Comment: In short: `--autopdf` doesn't work very well. Best to adjust the `compile_commands` in `textadept` directly.

Comment: Which files would those be?

Comment: `init.lua` in your `~/.textadept` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put something like this in your `init.lua`:

```
textadept.run.compile_commands.tex = 'mtxrun --autogenerate --script context --purge --synctex=-1 "%f"' and 'xdg-open "%e.pdf"'
```

Comment: Textadept is working again after installing textredux, but neither okular or xdg-open works, even when I tried them explicitly by /usr/bin/xdg-open etc

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ls2mrd0nbndpoiw/textadept.log?dl=0

Comment: Maybe try again: remove `~/.textadept`, start textadept, add the following line to `init.lua` →  `textadept.run.compile_commands.tex = 'mtxrun --autogenerate --script context --purge --synctex=-1 "%f"' and 'xdg-open "%e.pdf"'`

Comment: Yes!! That was it. Thanks so much!! I'll mark this as the right aswer.